# How to refresh the GUI window in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to make a simple GUI with Tkinker that, when you press a button it adds 1 to the text on a label. However, the label simply remains at 0. Is there a way I can refresh it so it stays up-to-date?

heres what i have so far:

```
from Tkinter import *
clicks = 0
def click():
    global clicks
    global Window
    clicks += 1
    print 'ok', clicks

def close_window():
    global Window
    Window.destroy()

Window = Tk()
Number = Label(text = clicks)
close = Button(Window , text='exit' , command = close_window)
button = Button(Window,text = 'clickme' ,command = click)
button.pack()
close.pack()
Number.pack()
Window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clicks += 1` only changes the variable `clicks`.

Use `Label.config(text=...)` or `Label['text'] = ...` to change the label text.

```
def click():
    global clicks
    clicks += 1
    Number.config(text=clicks) # <------
    print 'ok', clicks
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it, but for your label you don't want to use "text", you want "textvariable".  However, this takes a StringVar as a variable, which forces a little bit of busywork:

```
Window = Tk()
strclicks = StringVar()
Number = Label(textvariable=clicks)
```

and within click():

```
    clicks += 1
    strclicks.set(clicks)
```

Using "text" evaluates the variable at creation; "textvariable" updates the label when the variable updates.

Comment: For such a simple problem, IMO a textvariable is overkill. Whether with or without a textvariable, updating requires a function call (either widget.configure or variable.set). The use of a textvariable requires an extra object while providing no real advantage over just directly configuring the label.

Comment: @BryanOakley That's a reasonable position.  Before I started on Python, I was a long-time Tcl user, so my attitude towards textvariable is influenced by that.  In Tcl, the variable doesn't need to be a special object and it just works, no call necessary.  I actually wrote my answer up like that before the other answer went live, went to test it as confirmation, and re-discovered the need for the StringVar.  I edited my answer to use the StringVar and actually be correct, but I have to agree that using .config is simpler for this case.